# Error while using CosmosDB provider for Entity Framework Core with Azure Tables

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to do a simple CRUD application with EF Core and Azure Table (from Azure Storage Account).

I'm passing name of the storage account as database name (The docs aren't exactly clear on that)

```
services.AddDbContext<HomioDbContext>(options =>    
                options.UseCosmos(
                    "https://homiostorage.table.core.windows.net/",
                    "{Account Key}",
                    databaseName: "{name of storage account}"));
```

Doing any db operation throws following error (**The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format**)

```
CosmosException;StatusCode=BadRequest;SubStatusCode=0;ActivityId=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000;RequestCharge=0;Message=Response status code does not indicate success: 400 Substatus: 0 Reason: (<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?><error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">  <code>InvalidHeaderValue</code>  <message xml:lang="en-US">The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.RequestId:cdef27c9-3002-0084-60dd-d9b8b0000000Time:2020-02-02T15:29:31.9748413Z</message></error>, Request URI: /, RequestStats: , SDK: Windows/10.0.18363 cosmos-netstandard-sdk/3.3.0).;Diagnostics
```

Been stuck at it for a while now... Could really use some help!

Comment: Just a wild guess, can you try providing the name of the table for databaseName?

Comment: Another thing I noticed here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/cosmos/index?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) is that it is only available for SQL API and not Table Storage API. Could that be the reason?

Comment: @GauravMantri Is it the case? I was not familiar with that.. That could be the reason I suppose.. Will check up some sources on that!

Comment: @GauravMantri Yeah, that was the case.. Thanks!

Comment: Meaning no support for Table Storage, right?

Comment: @GauravMantri Yeah!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the documentation [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/cosmos/index?tabs=dotnet-core-cli), EF Core Provider for Cosmos DB only supports SQL API only (at least as of writing this answer) and you are using it against Table Storage. That's the reason you're getting this error.